Flask app doesn't recognize new routes that I add
I have some troubles with a Flask application I'm trying to run.
When I make a curl call to this server (the url points to the server's localhost, e.g. http://localhost:5000/[FLASK_ROUTE]), the Flask app is instanced by a script (main.py), which looks like this:
from flask import Flask
from routes_en import spacy_en_api

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(spacy_en_api)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()

which then routes to another file (routes_en.py), which looks like this:
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

spacy_en_api = Blueprint('spacy_en_api', __name__)

@spacy_en_api.route("/[MY_CUSTOM_ROUTE]", methods=['POST'])
def [MY_CUSTOM_ROUTE]():
data["output"] = "test - it works"
return jsonify(data)

@spacy_en_api.route("/en_parse_text", methods=['POST'])
def en_parse_text():
# code here

where "en_parse_text" is code written by someone before me. This part of the script works fine when called (http://localhost:5000/en_parse_text returns the expected output).
However, when I insert a new route (MY_CUSTOM_ROUTE), I get no output. When I check the logs, it reads "127.0.0.1 - - [DATE] "POST /MY_CUSTOM_ROUTE HTTP/1.1 404 -".
What's more: if I write new code in an existing route (e.g. I replace "# code here" with "print("testing")", the curl call returns not my code, but the code that I replaced/commented out.
Also might be important: Flask version is 1.1.1 / Python 3.7.3 / Werkzueg 0.15.5
What could cause the app to not recognize my new route? Thanks in advance for the help.

How are you running your flask code? Are you running it in debug mode with auto reloading on?

Please try the following:
In routes_en.py:
spacy_en_api_blueprint = Blueprint('spacy_en_api_blueprint', __name__)
    
@spacy_en_api_blueprint.route("/spacy_en_api", methods=['POST'])
def spacy_en_api():
  data["output"] = "test - it works"
  return jsonify(data)

in main.py:
from routes_en import spacy_en_api_blueprint
...
app.register_blueprint(spacy_en_api_blueprint)

Maybe you used the same method name in routes_en.py as the Blueprint variable and, therefore, imported the wrong object.
Also, I assumed that data was defined before as in data = {}.

The solution was to restart the app, but thanks for the input. Also, thanks for mentioning that I should define "data". I had done this earlier but forgot to copy it when pasting here.
